# Is there a way to decrypt an encoded string without a key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encryption, base64, aes, blowfish

Here's the problem, a string has been passed through three separate encryptions in the following order: Original -> Base64 -> AES-256 -> Blowfish (Keyless) -> Final. Write a method that takes this triple encoded string `mystery_string = "OXbVgH7UriGqmRZcqOXUOvJt8Q4JKn5MwD1XP8bg9yHwhssYAKfWE+AMpr25HruA"` and fully unencrypts it to its original state.

I looked into different libraries/documentation for aes256 and blowfish but all of them required a key. The only one that did not require a key was Base64 (i.e. `Base64.encode64('some string')` ). Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Your statement of the problem does not say that the the keys for AES-256 and Blowfish are not known to you.  I don't think decryption can be done without those keys. Are you sure the two keys are not known to you?

Comment: Yes. That's all the information I have. I was able to decode the encoded string using this [site](https://encode-decode.com/). Here's how it was broken down.

```blowfish_str = "OXbVgH7UriGqmRZcqOXUOvJt8Q4JKn5MwD1XP8bg9yHwhssYAKfWE+AMpr25HruA"```

```aes256_str = "M2yF9+kNzRnl+KQkm3DrQVBZ1WNyeUDFtqx0H8bz35E="```

```base64_str = "SSA8MyBSdWJ5IQ=="```

```plain_text = "I <3 Ruby!"```

Comment: Yes, I got the same. Is the problem just a Ruby coding exercise or are you taking a course on encryption algorithms? Either way, it seems like you're being asked to investigate code-breaking algorithms for those two encryption methods. Very strange.

Comment: It is for a Ruby coding exercise and honestly, I can't find any library in Ruby or any gems that decrypts aes256 & blowfish encryption without and given key

Comment: It strikes me as a tremendous time-waster as an exercise for teaching a computer language.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the only way to crack AES-256 and Blowfish without the key is by brute force enumeration of every possibly 32-byte combination that could be used as the key.  In theory, this means it's not crackable in our lifetime.  There may be some vulnerabilities you could exploit as you also have the plain text, but I doubt you would have that in a real-life situation.

Second, and most importantly, just going by that site, [encode-decode.com](https://encode-decode.com/)https://encode-decode.com/, you don't actually have enough information to decode the string even if you did know the password.

The various modes of operation for the AES256 cipher function requires either a 32-byte (or sometimes a 64-byte) key.  The secret that you used (you may have just left it blank) needs to be converted into a 32-byte encryption key.  This is done using a hashing algorithm, but we don't know which one is used.  Hopefully, the site used a key derivation function, which provides several security benefits.  However, key derivation functions require multiple parameters, and we would need to know what parameters to enter along with our secret to get the right encryption key.

Finally, we don't know if the secret is being concatenated with a salt before being hashed.  Without knowing if a salt is used and what the salt is, we cannot determine the correct 32-byte key used to encrypt the plain text.

In summary, the answer to your question is: No, there is not a quick way to decrypt that string without knowing the key.

However, encryption is an awesome topic to learn.

I'd encourage you to look over the ruby docs for the [OpenSSL library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html).  They're actually quite good (besides the don'ts I mention below).

The [PBKDF2 Password-based Encryption function](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-PBKDF2+Password-based+Encryption) is one of the key derivation functions I was referring to.

When encrypting with AES, you will most likely want to use [AES-256-GCM](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29) which is authenticated encryption.

A couple of don'ts:

- Don't use ciphers at random... understand their strengths and weaknesses
- Don't use AES-128-EBC - [explination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB))

Another good encryption library is [rb-NaCl](https://github.com/crypto-rb/rbnacl).